# C#: Get Properties of a class implemented from an interface

Tags: c#-4.0, interface, properties, system.reflection

I have been trying to get properties inside a class which implements an interface. My design is as below,

```
interface ABC
{
  string Name { get; set; }
}

public class BCD:ABC
{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Age{ get; set; }
 public string Height{ get; set; }
 public string Weight{ get; set; }
}
```

Now using Reflection I have tried this,

```
main()
{
  ABC abcObj = new BCD();
  var typeOfObject = typeof(abcObj);
  var objectProperties = typeOfObject.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance);
}
```

What i got in objectproperties were the properties in the ABC class. However i need the properties from the BCD class too.

Can someone help on this?

Comment: Have you tried casting it as a BCD class?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `typeof` (as that applies to class/interface names) try

```
var typeOfObject = abcObj.GetType();
```

to get the type of the instance.

When I run

```
ABC abcObj = new BCD();
var objectProperties = abcObj.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

for (int i = 0; i < objectProperties.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", objectProperties[i].Name, objectProperties[i].PropertyType);
}
```

I get the following in the console:

> Name (System.String)
>
> Age (System.String)
>
> Height (System.String)
>
> Weight (System.String)